# How to make net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser parse 000123123123 field as String, not as number

Tags: java, json, parsing, jsonparser

I'm using net.minidev.json.parser.JSONParser to parse json string to Object

Problem is, I don't want it to parse "000123456789" values as 123456789.

Is there a way to make parser ignore leading zeros?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that i used a JSON string like this one:

```
{ value: 000012345}
```

When I switched to

```
{ value: "00012345"}
```

it worked as I expected.